# How to start software update programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I need to start update android operating system on clicking the notification .
I am using this code :

```
Intent callGPSSettingIntent =new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DEVICE_INFO_SETTINGS);
        startActivityForResult(callGPSSettingIntent,1);
```

but it only move the user to "About device"   section and then user can see the option for Software update .

My requirement is to go one more step deeper and software update start automatically when user click on the notification.

Comment: Android will not allow you this permission to directly start update

Comment: Is there any other way for this ?  can system app have this kind of privilege ?

Comment: A workaround is sending a key or touch event after start activity. Didn't try if it works in Android app. These three commands `input`, `sendevent`, `getevent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call this function from activity:

```
openSettingsPage(this, "android.settings.SYSTEM_UPDATE_SETTINGS");
```

and

```
public void openSettingsPage(Context context, String setting) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(setting, null);

    final boolean isAndroidJellyBean = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN
        && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    if (isAndroidJellyBean || !areSettingsAvailable(context, intent)) {
        intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
    }

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}

public Boolean areSettingsAvailable(Context context, Intent intent) {
    List<ResolveInfo>
        activities = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    return activities != null && activities.size() > 0;
}
```